# UITableView - set Footer and Header - how i set scrolling with table view cell

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I must implemented TableView with Header and Footer view. I have all implemented but when the tableView is created, footer and header stay still in my screen.

[image]

And i want that my Footer will be on the bottom on last cell in table view, and she will appear when I scroll down on bottom of tableview. 
So as like a Header, When  i will by scrolling down header stay Top on table view. Anyone can help me ? 
My code:

Controllr which contains tableView:

```
@IBOutlet weak var tableView: UITableView! {
    didSet {
        let headerNib = UINib(nibName: SearchingHeader.headerID, bundle: nil)
        tableView.register(headerNib, forHeaderFooterViewReuseIdentifier: SearchingHeader.headerID)

        let cellNib = UINib(nibName: SearchingResultTableViewCell.cellId, bundle: nil)
        tableView.register(cellNib, forCellReuseIdentifier: SearchingResultTableViewCell.cellId)

        let footerNib = UINib(nibName: SearchingFooter.footerId, bundle: nil)
        tableView.register(footerNib, forHeaderFooterViewReuseIdentifier: SearchingFooter.footerId)
    }
}

extension SearchingViewController: UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource {

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return 10
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, viewForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> UIView? {
    let header = tableView.dequeueReusableHeaderFooterView(withIdentifier: SearchingHeader.headerID) as! SearchingHeader
    header.objectForSearch = objectOfSearch
    header.addressOnSearch = addressOfSearch
    return header.contentView
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> CGFloat {
    return 132
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, viewForFooterInSection section: Int) -> UIView? {
    let footer = tableView.dequeueReusableHeaderFooterView(withIdentifier: SearchingFooter.footerId) as! SearchingFooter
    return footer.contentView
}


func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForFooterInSection section: Int) -> CGFloat {
    return 243
}


func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {

}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: SearchingResultTableViewCell.cellId, for: indexPath) as! SearchingResultTableViewCell
    return cell
}
```

Header xib:
[image]

```
class SearchingHeader: UITableViewHeaderFooterView {

/// OUTLETS ///
@IBOutlet weak var mapButton: EnhancedButton! {
    didSet {
        mapButton.setImage(Asset.Icons.icoMap.image, for: .normal)
        mapButton.imageColor = UIColor.white
        mapButton.cornerRadius = 5
        mapButton.backgroundColor = ColorName.mainTurquoise.color
    }
}
@IBOutlet weak var objectOfSearchingTextField: LocalizedTextField!
@IBOutlet weak var searchIconImageView: EnhancedImageView! {
    didSet {
        searchIconImageView.imageColor = ColorName.mainOrange.color
    }
}

@IBOutlet weak var collectionView: UICollectionView! {
    didSet {
        collectionView.layer.backgroundColor = ColorName.mainGrey.color.cgColor
        let cellNib = UINib(nibName: SearchFilterCollectionViewCell.cellId , bundle: nil)
        collectionView.register(cellNib, forCellWithReuseIdentifier: SearchFilterCollectionViewCell.cellId )
    }
}

/// PROPERTIES ///
static var headerID: String = "Header"

var objectForSearch: String? {
    didSet {
        setSearchParameters()
    }
}
var addressOnSearch: String? {
    didSet {
        setSearchParameters()
    }
}
/// METHODS
override func awakeFromNib() {
    super.awakeFromNib()
    setUpView()
}
```

Footer is created in the same way.

Comment: you can take header view out side tableview and you need to manage or calculate call in table view as per cell in tableview you need to manage tableview height.

when you decrease size of tableview that automatically footer view is with the tableview..

Comment: I can't take header or footer outside on table. They must by a part of Table view. Must by Header . 10 times TableVieCell and Footer. And all of it must by like a scrollview. Header on TOP and footer on Bottom

Comment: Take the Footer view as the last cell and keep header view as it is. or you can try to change Table view style to the group.

Comment: Group help me!!! Thanks very much bro!!!!